# Cartesian product to Join

Tags: sql, relational-algebra, cartesian-product

Here is the deal, I have this SQL query

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers AS C, Orders AS O, Orderlines AS OL
WHERE C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID AND O .OrderID = OL.OrderID
```

which in relational algebra is

```
Σ(C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID AND O.OrderID=OL.OrderID)(Customers x Orders x Orderlines) .
```

How can I "convert" this 3-way Cartesian product into  a Join relation ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S Please correct me if I am wrong about the relational algebra part.

Comment: Ah, relational algebra. Such *fond* memories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems pretty straight forward...

```
SELECT c.*, o.*, ol.*
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN OrderLines ol ON o.OrderId = ol.OrderId
```

I'd advise against selecting `*` from every table though, especially given the duplicated column names.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers AS C
     JOIN Orders AS O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
     JOIN Orderlines AS OL ON O.OrderID = OL.OrderID
```